# Why is the index.php downloaded instead of rendered by Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I have been banging my head for 2 days now. The issue is that the `index.php` is downloaded instead of being processed. I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04` , `Nginx`, `php5`. The `nginx/site-available/default` is as below. I have added the `index.php` entry as prescribed by many posts.

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }


    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}



    #server {
    #   listen 8000;
    #   listen somename:8080;
    #   server_name somename alias another.alias;
    #   root html;
    #   index index.php index.html index.htm;
    #
    #   location / {
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #   }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #   listen 443;
    #   server_name localhost;
    #
    #   root html;
    #   index index.php index.html index.htm;
    #
    #   ssl on;
    #   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
    #   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
    #
    #   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    #
    #   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    #   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #
    #   location / {
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #   }
    #}
```

The `nginx.conf` is as below..

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
    }

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Solution followed till now.

1. added the entry of `index.php`
2. deleted the line `default_type application/octet-stream;` in
   nginx.conf
3. uncommented the `fastcgi` entries in `default` file.

I also tried these solution on the same problem but they didn't work for me.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747980/nginx-and-php-fpm-is-downloading-index-php-instead-of-processing-it
- one more link like it on stack overflow, along side many on other
  websites.

Answer (score 45):

Sometimes it can be as simple as **clearing the browser cache**. If there was some misconfiguration and it was indeed downloading files, after fixing the config the browser needs to be told to stop using the cached download.

Comment: Can't believe I spent an hour on this.. Good tip, +1

Comment: still valid in 2016 :))

Comment: still valid in 2021, spent like 2 hours debugging everything. what a time waster....

Comment: still valid in 2022. Banged my head against this for 2 days... Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you installed php-fpm ,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
```

now edit your `nginx/site-available/default` file and `location ~ \.php$` block

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

restart nginx service

`sudo service nginx reload`

and reload php5-fpm

`sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Comment: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` seems to be mssing in this block. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23443398/2010467

Comment: My location block is identical to this, except with `include fastcgi.conf` instead of `fastcgi_params` (I'm on ubuntu 14.10) and it's still downloading PHP files instead of executing them.

Answer (score 0):

> First you have to `Remove cache` in your browser

Then open terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gettext
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Then add the following code in the `default` file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If any mismatch just correction and restart Nginx from terminal by the following command

> sudo systemctl restart nginx

Then go to browser and Enjoy ...

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of `fpm php-mysql` installed on the server and `php-fpm.sock` in the configuration file.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com
```

The fpm versions should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons

1. **Misconfiguration on the server**. Fix the configuration and clear the cache of the browser.

*If you are using c-panel and you changed the PHP version for the site (Then c-panel will create a .htaccess file with some configuration) but when uploading a new `.htaccess` file which will replace the old one (created by c-panel).*

2. **Browser cache**. The solution is as simple as clearing the browser cache.