# Ubuntu Server 17.04 - 403 Forbidden

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, 17.04

Have Instlled for my Server all needed Services as:

> - OpenSSH Server
> - PHP7.1
> - MySQL
> - phpMyAdmin
> - Apache Tomcat8
> - FTP (vsftpd)

but got still 403 Forbidden on Browser when trying to open a simple index.php file.

using *000-default.conf*, configured the *apache2.conf* as well apache2 *ports.conf*. Portwardfowrding on router looks like working fine. checked Permissions with `chmod` as well on `www-data`and on *User*, but I'm stuck in 403 Forbidden.
I've already checkd tons of forums, and reading a lot about, but couldn't find my solution, anyone has some good hints out there?

**=========================== Configuration - Update ===========================**

I keept everything prrety simple after installtion, quite everything is by default, expection to some configurations:
`sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf`

```
Listen 192.168.1.104:82

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 82
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 82
</IfModule>
```

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.104:82>

    ServerAdmin user.name@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

     <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html>
              #  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
              #  AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

**=========================== Update 2 ===========================**

Finally the 403 Forbidden could be partly solved with a
`chmod -R 755 /var/www/html` Still no access as desired. Now *Site can't be reached* but downloads diretly the index file once entering in browser. So issue still not solved.

Comment: Could you please post the changes you did each configuration file and how did you install each of the services. This way we have an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado: check edit on main Post, what do you think?

Comment: Beautiful work. That will help a lot. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are using nginx to serve PHP .. if yes then where is PHP block .

Comment: see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/460710/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460710/)

Comment: @LuisAlvarado ;)

Comment: @AlokYadav: the answer your've provided is unfortunately not the solution for this case. Already read this post to get inspired by the simple things of life, I suppose the issue is pretty tricky! ;)

Comment: Try to change `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.104:82>` with `<VirtualHost *:82>`, I'm almost sure this will help. Also in `ports.conf`, I think that, you don't need IP there, just `Listen 82` and change next two ports to `83` - HTTP and HTTPS can't use the same port simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change these:

1. `chmod 775 -R /var/www/html`
2. `chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html`
3. add this:`AllowOverride all
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all`

tell me if any worked for you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57776/discussion-on-answer-by-nadav-tasher-ubuntu-server-17-04-403-forbidden).